# Discrepancy in outputs of `size` and `objdump`?

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, disassembly, objdump

I have compiled the following C function (in sum.c) into object code:

```c
int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return (a + b);
}
```

using

```
gcc -c sum.c
```

When I check the sizes of different sections using `size`:

```
size sum.o
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    112       0       0     112      70 sum.o
```

it tells me that the text section is allocated 112 bytes. But when I disassemble it using `objdump`:

```c
objdump -d sum.o

sum.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <sum>:
   0:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
   4:   55                      push   %rbp
   5:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   8:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   b:   89 75 f8                mov    %esi,-0x8(%rbp)
   e:   8b 55 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%edx
  11:   8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
  14:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
  16:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  17:   c3                      retq
```

There are only 17 bytes worth of instructions in the `.text` section. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Note: That 17 is hex, so in decimal that is 23. But that is 0x17(23) is the start of the last instruction. There are actually 24 bytes worth of instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `size -A` and `objdump -D` to get all the information you want.

On my system `size` without `-A` adds the size of the `.eh_frame` section onto text (probably because it is read-only and will be loaded together with the text).

Comment: `size` without options seems to return all the ALLOC/LOAD/READONLY as `.text`. It also will include things like `.note.gnu.property` (if GCC is emitting it) and as you noticed `.eh_frame` sections. Same for `.rodata` if it existed. In the OP's case it appears that the 112 is the size of `.eh_frame` (56) + `.text` (24) + `.note.gnu.property` (32) = 112 . With `size` the sections have also been padded out to multiples of 8 (which happens to be the alignment for each of the sections)